# Create a private album on Facebook for private automatic upload of photos from mobile?

Tags: facebook, privacy, photos

How can I create a private album on Facebook that would allow me to automatically upload of photos from mobile that will be private until I later make them manually available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a smartphone with a Facebook app (iPhone, Android), what you can do is create an album and set its visibility to "Only Me". Upload your photos from your smartphone into that album using the app. When you are ready to share those photos with the world, you can navigate to them using the desktop version of the website, and click Share. From there you can also set the appropriate privacy settings for the shared photos.

That's the closest I've found to what you're looking for, because at least the iPhone app does not allow you to Share a photo from one of your album, unfortunately.

Comment: Where do you set the visibility to "Only Me" in a Facebook album? Can you do this on the website or the Facebook app only?

Comment: @130490868091234 I believe you can only do this on the website. The idea is that you would create this album beforehand, and thankfully only once. Then you could always upload photos to it.